# Codeigniter write chainable functions

Tags: codeigniter

Can I write chainable functions in CodeIgniter?

So if I have functions like these :

```
function generate_error(){
    return $data['result']      =   array('code'=> '0',
                                      'message'=> 'error brother');
}

function display_error(){
      $a= '<pre>';
      $a.= print_r($data);
      $a.= '</pre>';
      return $a;
}
```

I want to call those by chaining them :

```
echo $this->generate_error()->display_error();
```

The reason why I want to seperate these functions are because display_error() is only useful for development, so when it comes to production, I can just remove the display_error() or something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write chainable functions they musy be part of a class, from the function you then return a reference to the current class (usually `$this`). 
If you return anything other than a reference to a class it will fail.

It is also possible to return a reference to another class (e.g. when you use the code igniter active records class `get()` function it returns a reference to the `DBresult` class)

```
class example {

  private $first = 0;
  private $second = 0;

  public function first($first = null){
    $this->first = $first;
    return $this;
  }

  public function second($second = null){
    $this->second = $second;
    return $this;
  }

  public function add(){
    return $this->first + $this->second;
  }
}

$example = new example();

//echo's 15
echo $example->first(5)->second(10)->add();

//will FAIL
echo $example->first(5)->add()->second(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return `$this` in your function to make chain-able functions in php oop

```
public function example()
{ 
 // your function content
 return $this;
}
```